# How to pull contents from a page into small div section of existing page in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a list of links on a page:

```
                                       PAGE 1
```

Link.1

Link.2

Link.3

Link.4

Etc.

I want to make it possible for a user to click a link e.g. link 2 perhaps.. and have the contents of that page (that is stored in it's own file) to show up on the same page with out the page refreshing.

I would basically pull the contents into a div on the page. When ever another link is clicked I would like for the present content to disappear making room for the new content.

This kind of thing is NEW to me. I would appreciate if anyone could point me towards a tutorial which clearly shows how to do this.

I previously posted this question and there were some good links but this is totally new to me and the examples seemed quite confusing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
<div id="link2container"></div>
```

jquery

```
$("#link2ID").click(function(e){
$("#link2container").load("page2.html");
});
```

Comment: Works great, found some tutorials on youtube.